# Unable to set keyboard shortcut for opening Xonsh shell

Tags: linux, shell, gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

What am I supposed to put as the command while setting a keyboard shortcut to open **xonsh** in Linux?

Putting

> xonsh

as the command does not seem to work although

> subl

launches sublime.

*(I am using Kali 2.0).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xonsh should be run from within your terminal. I am running it in elementary OS and the command would read `pantheon-terminal xonsh`. Find out the terminal you are using as standard and edit the command above.

Comment: Actually the command needed was `gnome-terminal -e xonsh`. Didn't know about the `-e` at that time.

Comment: With pantheon-terminal they removed the requirement for the -e in the last iteration... Good to know it worked...